# Can Unix run a program every new running process?

Tags: unix, automation, background-process

I need to edit running processes based on what apps are launched, and also add programs to some apps, but it needs to run on my computer the whole time.

For example: If I am opening xcode, atom, or vs, I want to autosave(if applicable) and close larger programs like microsoft word, excel, and itunes.

I already know how to close apps through terminal, I was going to use c or c++ for the process since I can control how much memory it takes up a little better, but I can't find anything on running a process every time any app is used.

I also don't want to keep track of all running processes, as that would involve searching the running processes every time. That could work if I just count items returned, but then I would be counting items every block of time, which would either take up more processing power than necessary or not be automatic.

Comment: Okay, for anyone interested in this topic, here's an update:

I have decided to make(and have partially implemented) a program that replaces the main exe of the apps with my own compiled c code, which logs the time it was used and then checks the running apps, then runs the renamed version of the file. the file is just renamed with an underscore(_) in front, but that's all that is necessary.

Would love any input on adjustments to the process. Currently working on automation of the file renaming. If I make a github for this I'll post it here.

Comment: Based on your list of programs, I assume you're using OS X?

Comment: yeah, that's not a great solution though, so I'd love to hear any other ideas.

Comment: Okay, for an update: I have changed to a swift based app, as it allows for all of the functionality I need for macos. I would still like to try and find a way to write it for linux in the future, so am still open to suggestions.